# Vector decomposition in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, geometry

this is my situation: I have a 30x30 image and I want to calculate the radial and tangent component of the gradient of each point (pixel) along  the straight line passing through the centre of the image (15,15) and the same (i,j) point.

```
[dx, dy] = gradient(img);

for i=1:30
    for j=1:30
        pt = [dx(i, j), dy(i,j)];
        line = [i-15, j-15];
        costh = dot(line, pt)/(norm(line)*norm(pt));
        par(i,j) = norm(costh*line);
        tang(i,j) = norm(sin(acos(costh))*line);
    end
end
```

is this code correct?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a conceptual error in your code, I tried to get your results with a different approach, see how it compares to yours.

```
[dy, dx] = gradient(img);
```

I inverted x and y because the usual convention in matlab is to have the first dimension along the rows of a matrix while `gradient` does the opposite.

I created an array of the same size as `img` but with each pixel containing the angle of the vector from the center of the image to this point:

```
[I,J] = ind2sub(size(img), 1:numel(img));
theta=reshape(atan2d(I-ceil(size(img,1)/2), J-ceil(size(img,2)/2)), size(img))+180;
```

The function `atan2d` ensures that the 4 quadrants give distinct angle values.
Now the projection of the x and y components can be obtained with trigonometry:

```
par=dx.*sind(theta)+dy.*cosd(theta);
tang=dx.*cosd(theta)+dy.*sind(theta);
```

Note the use of the `.*` to achieve point-by-point multiplication, this is a big advantage of Matlab's matrix computations which saves you a loop.

Here's an example with a well-defined input image (no gradient along the rows and a constant gradient along the columns):

```
img=repmat(1:30, [30 1]);
```

The results:

```
subplot(1,2,1)
imagesc(par)
subplot(1,2,2)
imagesc(tang)
colorbar
```

[image: tangential and radial gradients gradient]